# Is it possible to have a voice command start-able activity without it being a launcher with an icon?

Tags: android, android-intent

So I have written an application that has a simple side-feature, like toggling the phones Wi-Fi.  I have read the Android Developer's article for '[Adding Voice Capabilities](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided)' and have successfully gotten the side-feature activity to be launched via Google Now voice command: "Start mySideFeature activity" without launching my whole app.

The problem is that in order for the activity to be launch-able via voice command, you have to declare its action .MAIN and its category .LAUNCHER. Which means my application will now have two launcher icons, The voice command activity, and the main app activity itself, showing up in the app drawer.

I have done some research and I couldn't find a way to reveal, from within the activity, whether an activity was started by tapping the launcher icon or via the voice command.

Is it possible to have a voice command start-able activity without it being a launcher with an icon?

Here's a simple version of my manifest, where you will see the issue of two activities with the intent-filter for a launcher.

```
<application>
  <activity android:name="MainAppActivity" android:label="Main App">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="sideFeatureActivity" android:label="Launch Side Feature">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: As a "hack" I would try this: debug your main activity, when launched via voice vs from launcher to see if there's a way to tell which case you are in. Look at getIntent(), and see what you have there? Bundle? Extra? If you know how to tell the difference, you can already figure out how to do the sideFeature thing or the mainActivity thing

Comment: Hmmm the only difference I see right off the start in the Intent returned from getIntent() is that when started by voice, the intent's 'categories' array  is null, whereas when it is started by the launcher icon, it has the '.LAUNCHER' item in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your main activity's onCreate add:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Set<String> categories = getCategories();
if (categories != null && categories.contains(".LAUNCHER")) {
   ... //Started via launcher tap
} else {
   ... //Started via voice command
}
```